# Cant figure out why this is giving me a TypeError

Tags: javascript

I have written a function wherein I want the arguments to be concatenated with a space:

```js
function sayIt(str) {
    
    var stringCollection = [];
    
    this.addToCollection = function(str){
        stringCollection.push(str);
        
        if(!str){  // for the () part in the call
            return stringCollection.join(" ");
        }
    };
    
    return this.addToCollection(str);
    
}


console.log(sayIt('my')('name')('is')('Harry')()); // should log "my name is Harry"
```

Its giving me a TypeError. Any idea, why?

Comment: `sayIt` doesn't return a function so you can't use `sayIt(...)(...)`

Comment: Why would you expect that to work?

Comment: @Phil I have added the return now. Its still the same.

Comment: @RahulDesai still not returning a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning a function when you have a word as an argument -- try this;

```js
function sayIt(str) {
    
    var stringCollection = [];
    
    function concat(str){
        stringCollection.push(str);
        
        if(!str){  // for the () part in the call
            return stringCollection.join(" ");
        }
        return concat;
    };
    return concat(str);        
}


alert(sayIt('my')('name')('is')('Harry')()); // should log "my name is Harry"
```

Comment: I understand why we need to do `return concat(str);` but not `return concat;`. Can you please elaborate? Why is it not like `return concat();`?

Comment: The `return concat` returns a function pointer, so you are able to chain the calls allong, like in `sayIt('my')('name')('is')('Harry')()` where `sayIt('my')` returns a function pointer which the `('name')` is executed against... etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite fancy the design of your method because it appears fragile to me, but I am sure you have a rationale behind it.

Modify

```
this.addToCollection = function(str){
    stringCollection.push(str);

    if(!str){  // for the () part in the call
        return stringCollection.join(" ");
    }
};
```

To

```
this.addToCollection = function(str){
    stringCollection.push(str);

    if(!str){  // for the () part in the call
        return stringCollection.join(" ");
    }
    return this.addToCollection;
};
```

Comment: Why is it fragile to you? Also, why does the closure function return the same function without any argument, but the outer one does?

Comment: @RahulDesai, first, this is purely a matter of opinion, so there is no right or wrong. The change in post was suggested purely on basis of how you have actually deployed it. Take a look at a chaining example from, say, underscorejs - the last call in typical chaining is to a value() method that returns the accumulated result. HTH